# Bootstrap v3.3.6 Navbar toggle button shows but doesn't display the Menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My Navbar works fine and everything on it about form when i try to collapse it, it shows everything, the button included but doesn't display the menu items. I have no idea why. I am using Bootstrap 3.3.6.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
 <div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Welcome</a>
  </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a> </li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
```

Comment: It's working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/p5px70t3/ what is the issue?

Comment: Seems to look fine except missing </nav> at the end http://bootply.com/hMASKdGwVk

Comment: Issue is with the button doesn't display the menu, i don't no why, i am using google chrome and when i shrink it and click the button, doesn't display the menu items

Comment: @Mrnerd in chrome also display the menu item. Check above JSFiddle.

Comment: @ketan it does work there but don't know why it wouldn't work in chrome my mac, no idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine in Codepen So my guess would be you forgot to include `JQuery` or `bootstrap.js` in your html page.

You can download JQuery from [here](https://jquery.com/download/).

Comment: I figured it out, it was the bootstrap i didn't have, now works after importing it.